# Have an unfocused C# program activate on keypress (eg. F1 sets a label to "Hello World")

Tags: c#, key, listener

I am trying to make my program activate its task if a key is pressed anywhere, even if it is not in focus. (lets just use F1 for this example, and have the task being set a text on a label to "Hello World").

I looked at key listeners, hooks etc and is getting a headache trying to understand what is going on. Is there any easy way to make this work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use WIN API [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309.aspx) function.

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern int RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hwnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);
```

Register hotkey on Form_Load event:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterHotKey(Handle, 42, 0, (int)Keys.F1);
}
```

Keep in mind that if you want to hook some keys combination, instead of zero you should pass one of following values (for Alt, Ctrl, Shift or Windows keys):

```
private const int MOD_ALT = 0x1;
private const int MOD_CONTROL = 0x2;
private const int MOD_SHIFT = 0x4;
private const int MOD_WIN = 0x8;
```

At this point when you press somewhere F1 key, system will send to your window [WM_HOTKEY message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646279.aspx). Process it inside WndProc:

```
private const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
    {
        if (!Visible)
            Visible = true;
        Activate();
        Keys vk = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
        int fsModifiers = ((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF);

        if (vk == Keys.F1 && sModifiers == 0)
            label.Text = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

BTW don't forget to [unregister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646327.aspx) hotkey when closing form.

Comment: What does the number 42 signify?

Comment: Thank you, gonna try this. :) you mentioned to unregister the hokey on exit. I am quite new to C# (and general Windows API calls) still, so I do know where to place the trigger, but I am wondering if you could help me with the actual command as above. I still do not understand those .dll calls well.

Comment: Thats an id of hokey. Just dummy number. If you need several hotkeys for one window, you need different ids.

Comment: @Taoh thats simple - place this static extern method declaration inside your Form class (like any other usual method).

Comment: Just wondering, that ID you are referencing only needs to be unique along with the "target windows process" to have a way to separate the characters. Is that correct? Also I am wondering how you ended up with the 0x312 for WM_HOTKEY. If I understand the vk part your dropping the modifiers (4 bit) and then comparing the recieved key press against F1, if I wanted the shift alt F1 I would have to have sModifiers == 12?

Comment: If you register sever several hotkeys with same id for one window (same hWnd), then only last one registered will work for you. See the link to WM_HOTKEY message definition. 0x312 is the id of this message. Nope, for shift you need compare modifiers with 0x4 or 4 (value for MOD_SHIFT).

Comment: You need bitwise operation (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1544/Bit-wise-operations-in-C), not simple adding. Alt+Shift will be `MOD_ALT | MOD_SHIFT`, or `5` if you want number.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this article [here](http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207), what you need are global hotkeys. The link I've provided encapsulates that into a very usable form.

Comment: Thank you for the link. From what I can see this link will help me better implement the above posters reference to RegisterHotKey and understand how to set it up correct. I am selecting the other post as the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into the [Win32 RegisterHotKey function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? That may be your best bet if you want to get keyboard input when another application has the foreground. You'll need to pinvoke or find a managed wrapper.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Need a bit of time to digest the information